# createPanner with gainNode in safari

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api, audiocontext

I want to pan left or right at a time and also set the volume for it, I have done it with other browsers but on safari createStereoPanner is not a function so i used createPanner for safari 
Now, Problem is that i want to use gain with panner to set volume currently its playing both gain and pan separately it should set gain for panner

here is my code

```
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', '/Asset/sounds/calibrate.mp3');
    audioElement.volume = 0.5;
    audioElement.play().then(function (d) {
        audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
        source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
        if (isSafari) {
            gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
            gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(audioElement.volume, audioCtx.currentTime);
            source.connect(gainNode);
            gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);

            panNode = audioCtx.createPanner();
            panNode.panningModel = 'HRTF';
            source.connect(panNode);
            panNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
            //panNode.setPosition(10, 0, 0);

        }
        else {
            panNode = audioCtx.createStereoPanner();
            panNode.pan.value = 0;
            source.connect(panNode);
            panNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        }
    });
```

im playing audio how to handle it

Comment: Hi Mike, if you don't want to maintain the fallback yourself you could also use [standardized-audio-context](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/standardized-audio-context). There is also a standalone polyfill ([stereo-panner-node](https://github.com/mohayonao/stereo-panner-node)) but that is unfortunately unmaintained by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of the PannerNode in webKit is still a little off. This has already been answered in [a previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52809552/how-to-pan-audio-in-ios-web-audio-implementation), though without a full working example and the added complexity of the gain node.

The output of panner is always stereo, so it should be the last in the chain. The connections should go

```
Source Sound -> GainNode -> PannerNode -> AudioContext.destination
```

Example code is given below and [a JSFiddle can be Found Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ovwmundc/). This example hard pans to the right channel.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script>
var audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
var gain = 0.01;
gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(gain, audioCtx.currentTime);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
var pan = 1; // This should be in range [-1, 1]

if (audioCtx.createStereoPanner)
{
  var panner = audioCtx.createPanner();
  panner.pan.value = pan;
}
else
{
  var panner = audioCtx.createPanner();
  panner.panningModel = 'equalpower';
  panner.setPosition(pan, 0, 1 - Math.abs(pan));
}

gainNode.connect(panner);
panner.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- ===================================================================== -->

  <body>

    <div>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
    <script>
function myFunction()
{
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------
  var duration = 0.5; // in seconds
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------
  var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
  oscillator.type = 'square';
  oscillator.frequency.value = 500;
  oscillator.connect(gainNode);
  oscillator.start(audioCtx.currentTime);
  oscillator.stop(audioCtx.currentTime + duration);
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------
}
    </script>
  </body>
  <!-- ===================================================================== -->

</html>
```

Comment: awesome man but i m playing audio element how to work it can you please see updated code

Comment: gainNode is not connecting to panner i need to set volume

Comment: @Mike it would probably be easier to have a basic, self contained working example of what you have as a jsfiddle.

Comment: mean while i have a question can we set the volume level of a panner ?

Comment: You would set the volume of the GainNode before the PannerNode. Think of it as the same signal chain you would find on an audio mixing desk

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ovwmundc/ in this example can you modify it if i want to play this (http://old.harappa.com/gandhi.mp3) audio on load and when click me button clicked just decrease the volume it would be enough for me thanks in advance really appreciated man (Y)

Comment: My recommendation is actually, if you want to do something interactive with WebAudio, you are probably better off using the [P5 Sound library](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.SoundFile). It should take care of what function calls to make regardless of browser with the added benefit that you don't need to maintain the library. Plus, panning and SoundFile loading is already implemented [with examples](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.SoundFile/pan) which is more than can be said for the Webkit/MDN docs.

Comment: if (audioCtx.createStereoPanner)
{
  var panner = audioCtx.createPanner();
  panner.pan.value = pan;
}  . . . 
 Shouldn't this be  audioCtx.createStereoPanner();